# Custom column display text gets applied to cells it shouldn't

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I got stuck while using the CustomColumnDisplayText Event. I am using this code:

```
private void gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column == colVehicle_FahrzeugartID && e.ListSourceRowIndex >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridViewList.DataRowCount; i++)
        {
            object cellValue = gridViewList.GetRowCellValue(i, "Vehicle_FahrzeugartID");
            this.clsFahrzeugart.ReadFromDb((int)cellValue);

            if (this.clsFahrzeugart.Systemstatus == 11 && e.ListSourceRowIndex == i)
            {
                e.DisplayText = "Deleted...";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to display deleted if the value Systemstatus is 11 which stands for deleted in my database and everything works fine but if I am toggling my switch there are empty values in my column and some values are getting changed to deleted although they dont have the value 11.

This is how it looks if the Switch is toggled:

[image]

And this is how it should look like:

[image]

```
bool isOn = toggleSwitch1.EditValue is bool ? (bool)toggleSwitch1.EditValue : false;
if (isOn)
{
    tbAutoBindingSource1.Filter = "Vehicle_Systemstatus = 1";
    btn_UnDel.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    tbAutoBindingSource1.Filter = "Vehicle_Systemstatus IS NOT NULL";
    btn_UnDel.Visible = true;
}
```

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you loop anything? Why don't you just get rid of this loop and replace `i` with `e.ListSourceRowIndex`? Also what does `this.clsFahrzeugart.ReadFromDb((int)cellValue);` do?

Comment: I am looping to get the value(Id) of each row which is my foreign key to antoher table than I am using this.clsFahrzeugart.ReadFromDb((int)cellValue) a method that I wrote to read out the data based on the foreign key to get Systemstatus and then check if it is 11.

Comment: Yes, but you do not **need** to "*get the value(Id) of each row*" as this event is already raised for **each** row. Thing about `this.clsFahrzeugart.ReadFromDb` is that we don't have the code for it so we can't know if it gets the right info. Anyway, see the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to traverse through all rows since this event is raised for an individual row. Since this event provides the [e.ListDataSourceRowIndex](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs.ListSourceRowIndex.property) property associated with a datasource row index, not a row handle, you need to use the [GridView.GetListSourceRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetListSourceRowCellValue.overloads) method to access a cell value.

Refer to the [Rows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3484/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Views/Grid-View/Rows) help topic to learn differences between datasource indexes and grid row handles.

```
private void gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = sender as GridView;
    if (e.Column == colVehicle_FahrzeugartID && e.ListSourceRowIndex >= 0)
    {
        object cellValue = view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "Vehicle_FahrzeugartID");
        this.clsFahrzeugart.ReadFromDb((int)cellValue);
        if (this.clsFahrzeugart.Systemstatus == 11)
            e.DisplayText = "Deleted...";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've taken the freedom to edit your post in order to fix the code format (indent)

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks for the fast answer and explanation.

Comment: You are welcome :).  @Rafalon, thank you for correcting the format.

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes in your code.

**0. Pointless cycle in event.**

The `CustomColumnDisplayText` event are used to display text in currently processed cell. So, all you need is to get values according to that cell.

**1. Wrong using of `GetRowCellValue` method.**

You need to use `RowHandle` for `GetRowCellValue`. `ListSourceRowIndex` is wrong here. `RowHandle` and `ListSourceRowIndex` are not the same. You need to use `GetRowHandle` method to get `RowHandle` from `ListSourceRowIndex`.

Here is example:

```
private void gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column == colVehicle_FahrzeugartID && e.ListSourceRowIndex >= 0)
    {
        int rowHandle = gridViewList.GetRowHandle(e.ListSourceRowIndex);
        object cellValue = gridViewList.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "Vehicle_FahrzeugartID");
        this.clsFahrzeugart.ReadFromDb((int)cellValue);

        if (this.clsFahrzeugart.Systemstatus == 11)
        {
            e.DisplayText = "Deleted...";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advices I just started programming a few weeks ago so I often do some mistakes